# What's rude, abusive or spam about this answer?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, spam

Today as I was reviewing a few low quality posts I came across one where I got this message:

> #### STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were
>   paying attention. **You didn't pass.** This post has severe quality
>   issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or
>   otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive
>   rather than helpful. Please **delete** or **recommend deletion** when
>   reviewing such posts.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

I've gotten this once before (and admittedly at the time I didn't pay attention, so it's cool to have this mechanism in place), but for this particular answer it strikes me as odd. It has a big **I understand** button which I am not willing to press, since I don't. Following the link to the answer I found this:

[image]

The answer in question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52728253/revisions).  Picture for users < 10K:

[image]

And for the life of me I can't see what's so bad about it. Especially this seems a bit of an exaggeration on *all* counts:

> It is abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise
>   irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.

I've seen similar recommendations all over the SE network and *without* being a domain expert of z/OS that recommendation *still* seems rather sensible to me, i.e. to recommend the GNU variety of a tool for their widespread use (which typically means if you run into issues you'll more easily find a solution to it). The only possible issue I could imagine with this is that the individual who answered is somehow affiliated with the company to which the link leads (i.e. didn't disclose the affiliation, which would be frowned upon). But no comment indicated anything of the kind either.

To recapitulate: the individual who was answering obviously recommended to use the GNU flavor of `sed` and gave a link where to find it. So what's the issue? The fact that the download requires an account on that website? That's what 10minutemail or spamgourmet is for. Or the fact that it mentions a company name?

Just to put this in perspective: by a similar answer I was led to a repository of AIX ports of certain GNU packages a while back and I was very grateful for that. The reason being that not all Unixes are created equal. In my case my employer committed to providing support for some of our products on AIX and therefore requires us to run particular tests on (outdated versions of) AIX; because the commitment only goes so far, obviously. Of course none of us received any training either, so we're left with [this](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) and the manual pages on the AIX system. Were I to be stuck in the same situation as the inquirer, I'd probably welcome and even upvote such an answer.

Can anyone shed some light on this with regard to **that linked answer**?! I've seen that I am not the only one confused about some of the audit outcomes (presumably the reason why [disputed-review-audits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) exists ...

Comment: I don't have 10k yet so I'm just spitballing in the dark here, but are there any links in the original revision that lead to unwanted destinations disguised as something else? That's a frequently overlooked part of reviews since it's not the explicit text that's inappropriate.

Comment: More than likely there's more to this user/answer than we can see.

Comment: @DavyM:  The link *does* point to where the OP at least claims it does, but since I'm at work I'm incredibly wary of clicking said link.

Comment: @DavyM: there is a link titled [z/OS Open Source Tools](https://www.rocketsoftware.com/zos-open-source/tools), yes.

Comment: The initial paragraph is marketing preamble.  That should put you on your guard from the get go.  A good way to test, though, is if someone is recommending a third party tool, do they tell you *how* to use said tool to solve the problem the question presents?  If not, it's a decent bet it's, at the very least, not an answer.

Comment: @KevinB if that's the case it would not seem to be a good match for the review audits, since I don't have full information. And the information I have/had didn't exactly let me come to the same conclusion as ChrisF, for example (the mod who closed it).

Comment: Take a look through the other "disputed-review-audits" for other examples of this happening. It's just a quirk of the system.

Comment: @KevinB actually I did. So you're saying I should simply ignore it (also subsequent instances) and move on. Do I get you right?

Comment: Basically. There's literally nothing you can do about it aside from try to identify audits as audits. In cases like this, clicking on the link to the question to get more information for example would have made it obvious that this is an audit.

Comment: @KevinB:  Because gaming the audit system is more substantial than actually understanding why this one *is* a valid audit...?

Comment: "gaming the audit system" does exactly what the audit system was put in place to accomplish: it slows you down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: @gnat how so? I _am_ using "Skip" regularly, also as moderator on one of the SE sites in order to let the community decide or when unsure in those edge cases. How is this a dupe of that question, though?

Comment: you said it yourself - "_without_ being a domain expert of z/OS" - this is 100% case when you better skip instead if picking positive review. It is only negative reviews when one can afford not being domain expert (and sometimes even not even reading the question - "I have same question, have you resolved this" doesn't need one to look at anything else). When you are going to positively review some post you need to invest much more effort. Or, well, skip if you aren't inclined to investigate

Comment: @gnat So you're saying the AIX example I gave cannot be compared ... isn't similar in the least? Sorry, I disagree. All those downvotes for my question aside.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was flagged as spam.

I don't remember handling this one specifically but my reasoning would be something along the following lines:

1. The flag is valid as it looks like spam.
2. The post needs to be deleted as it doesn't really answer the question.
3. The poster doesn't deserve to be hit with a 100 point rep penalty and have their IP blocked if I flag the post as spam.

Therefore, I just delete the post.

This marks the flag as helpful and hides the post from non-moderators.

Unfortunately it also has the side effect of making this post a potential audit post - something I always forget.

To change this a moderator would have to dispute the flag and then re-delete the post.

Comment: I see. That's also a nice gem in the last sentence, as I happen to be a pro-tem mod over on RE.SE. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand point #3 - the answer was marked as spam anyway wasn't it? Otherwise this meta wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Gimby: the flag may be valid, it does look spammish, but the link is for OSS software vaguely enough related to the question, and the account that posted it doesn't look like your typical spammer. A moderator can then decide avoid applying the account rep penalty and blocks by just deleting the post and not also spam flagging.

Comment: @Gimby: moderators have seen all sorts and we usually can tell the difference between someone self-promoting the hell out of their own pet OSS project or are pushing the project their workplace has built a support platform around vs. a genuine "I thought you'd like this project" posts. We can see if the account has posted similar things in the past but now deleted, we can do a search for the relevant URLs in deleted posts on the site to see if someone running an astroturfing campaign, etc. So we do want to see this kind of stuff flagged as spam, but don't always need to penalise the account.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yet it turned up in an audit. So does this mean that when a post has a spam flag on it and is then deleted with that flag being left in limbo, that will put it up for audit as if it actually was acknowledged as being spam? If so, then it seems quite wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Devoid of context, it reads like the OP is trying to sell you something, not necessarily *answer* the question.  Therefore, marking it as spam would be the correct choice.

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, I've seen many answers like this throughout and no one seems to care. Besides one very similar answer helped me (as outlined above) and plugging ports of FLOSS software doesn't strike me as "selling something".

Comment: @0xC0000022L spam is for "self promotion" not "selling something". There's a subtle difference we don't require there to be money involved in the transaction for it to be spam.

Comment: @0xC0000022L:  Assume no domain knowledge or any expertise whatsoever when looking at a response like that. An answer should be capable of providing *some* context as a response to a question.  An answer which says, "Hey, use this tool and here's a link to where you can download it" feels less like an answer and more like marketing.  Just because you've seen answers like this receive an apathetic welcome doesn't mean *you* get to receive them apathetically.

Comment: Wait! The question shows the inquirer failing with the system-provided `sed` flavor (oh yeah, I _was_ paying attention enough to notice that) and the answer recommended a more widespread alternative flavor of said tool. Didn't seem all out of place. But I think the last sentence of your previous comment brings your point home better than your actual answer.

Comment: @0xC0000022L:  I didn't look at the question.  In reviews, unless I want that extra context, I don't normally go look at the question.  I think we've established that, at a minimum, the question is "Not an answer" since it doesn't give enough context to a random passer-by to discern if this is their intent or not.